# How to group by and sum an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I would like to group an array of objects by `Id` and sum the quantity in jQuery. How can I achieve this?

For example:

```
var array = [
  { Id: "001", qty: 1 },
  { Id: "002", qty: 2 },
  { Id: "001", qty: 2 },
  { Id: "003", qty: 4 }
]
```

Should result in:

```
[
  { Id: "001", qty: 3 },
  { Id: "002", qty: 2 },
  { Id: "003", qty: 4 }
]
```

Comment: An updated, TypeScript-friendly SO that also supports multiple grouping keys is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76272302/8929855)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can loop and sum it up ([**reduce** documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))

```js
var array = [
  { Id: "001", qty: 1 }, 
  { Id: "002", qty: 2 }, 
  { Id: "001", qty: 2 }, 
  { Id: "003", qty: 4 }
];

var result = [];
array.reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.Id]) {
    res[value.Id] = { Id: value.Id, qty: 0 };
    result.push(res[value.Id])
  }
  res[value.Id].qty += value.qty;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p8e0q0p5/)

Comment: setting `qty` to 0 is important in the `res[value.Id] = { qty: 0, Id: value.Id};` step. Otherwise u get duplicate values

Comment: Should this not be var result = array.reduce.... instead of using a sideeffect?

Comment: I believe this only work because the Id is numeric cause the Index of the array cannot be a string...

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArr = [];

$.each(array,function(index,element){
    if(newArr[element.Id]==undefined){
        newArr[element.Id] =0;
    }
    newArr[element.Id] += element.qty;
});
console.log(newArr);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j3hu13mj/)**

Comment: You are not creating an array of objects

Comment: This uses element.id as an array index, not as an object key.