# How to collect the same items in a list in Angular

Tags: typescript, list

I have a list like this :
[image]

And I want to collect this list to a other list with collect the same items.

I want new list result like below

```
    { mold: "T1164021", panchiNumber: 30 }
    { mold: "T2034101", panchiNumber: 8 }
    { mold: "T3726101", panchiNumber: 8 }
    { mold: "T3049021", panchiNumber: 4 }
    { mold: "T1024031", panchiNumber: 36 }
    { mold: "T3099051", panchiNumber: 28 }
```

Can someone tell me what I should do to get a new list like that?

Thank you for read my post !

Comment: Would something like this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364262/how-to-group-by-and-sum-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `array.reduce` method.

```js
const parentArr = [
    { mold: 'T1164021', panchiNumber: 12},
    { mold: 'T1164021', panchiNumber: 12},
    { mold: 'T1164021', panchiNumber: 6},
    { mold: 'T2034101', panchiNumber: 8},
    { mold: 'T3726101', panchiNumber: 8},
    { mold: 'T3049021', panchiNumber: 4},
    { mold: 'T1024031', panchiNumber: 12},
    { mold: 'T1024031', panchiNumber: 12},
    { mold: 'T1024031', panchiNumber: 12},
    { mold: 'T3099051', panchiNumber: 4},
    { mold: 'T3099051', panchiNumber: 12},
    { mold: 'T3099051', panchiNumber: 12},
]
const newArr = parentArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const node = acc.find((item) => item.mold === curr.mold);
    if (node) {
        node.panchiNumber += curr.panchiNumber;
    } else {
        acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newArr)
```