# Combine value with same date in multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have one array which has two values one date and an amount but there is the same date with a different value at a different index so I need to merge those values into the same date in a multidimensional javascript array

current array

```
var arry = [
['2021-05-01',100], 
['2021-05-02',300], 
['2021-05-03',200], 
['2021-05-01',150],
['2021-05-02',300], 
['2021-05-01',600],
['2021-05-04',120]
]
```

Expected Result Array

```
var arry = [
['2021-05-01',850], 
['2021-05-02',600], 
['2021-05-03',200], 
['2021-05-04',120]]
```

Can anybody help? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: `Object.values(arry.reduce((acc,[k,v]) => { acc[k] = [ k, (acc[k]?.[1] || 0) + v]; return acc;}, {}))`

Comment: @epascarello you're creating a new array on every iteration instead of just updating as the answers below do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group by and sum an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364262/how-to-group-by-and-sum-an-array-of-objects) (arrays are objects...)

Comment: @pilchard does not matter, still works.

Comment: Save micoseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `reduce`. I'm creating an object grouped by date and taking the values array of it

```js
var arry = [['2021-05-01',100], ['2021-05-02',300], ['2021-05-03',200], ['2021-05-01',150],['2021-05-02',300], ['2021-05-01',600],['2021-05-04',120]]

const res = Object.values(arry.reduce((acc,[date,val])=> {
    acc[date] = acc[date] || [date,0]
  acc[date][1]+=val
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `acc[date] ??= [date,0]` [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Comment: @pilchard wow i wasnt aware

Comment: thanks @cmgchess for the quick help it really works

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` method:

```js
var arry = [
  ['2021-05-01',100], 
  ['2021-05-02',300], 
  ['2021-05-03',200], 
  ['2021-05-01',150],
  ['2021-05-02',300], 
  ['2021-05-01',600],
  ['2021-05-04',120]
];

const data = arry.reduce((list, [date, value]) =>  {
  list[date] = (list[date] ?? 0) + value;
  return list;
}, {});
const list = Object.entries(data); // if you want the array

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could likely just loop through the list, and at each value in the list check all of the values that came before to see if it is a repeat. Something like the following would work:

```
var array = [
  ['2021-05-01',100], 
  ['2021-05-02',300], 
  ['2021-05-03',200], 
  ['2021-05-01',150],
  ['2021-05-02',300], 
  ['2021-05-01',600],
  ['2021-05-04',120]
]

var newArray = []; // where we will put the new merged values

for (var lookAtOldArray = 0; lookAtOldArray < array.length; lookAtOldArray++) {
  // check all previous values in newArray up to this point:
  var checkNewArray; // declare out here for logic post loop
  for (checkNewArray = 0; checkNewArray < newArray.length; checkNewArray++) {
    if (array[lookAtOldArray][0] == newArray[checkNewArray][0]) {
      // add to newArray number:
      newArray[checkNewArray][1] += array[lookAtOldArray][1];
      break; // BREAK to signify we found a position
    }

    // otherwise keep looking
  }

  // because of the break, if checkNewArray == newArray.length, then we DID NOT find a duplicate (AKA: push to newArray with exact value in array)
  if (checkNewArray == newArray.length) {
     newArray.push(array[lookAtOldArray]);
  }
}
```

another interesting idea would be to use objects. The above strategy would require looking the data more times than necessary (n^2 for worst cases). With an object, you could use the date as a key, and the number as the value. With that, you could do something like this (assuming the same declaration of `array`:

```
var combinedDates = {};

for (var lookAtOldArray = 0; lookAtOldArray < array.length; lookAtOldArray++) {
  combinedDates[array[lookAtOldArray][0]] += array[lookAtOldArray[1];
}
```

You can tell this is a lot faster and simpler. The resulting object would look like this:

```
{
  "2021-05-01": 850,
  "2021-05-02": 600,
  "2021-05-03": 200,
  "2021-05-04": 120
}
```

I'm preferential to the second one because of the efficiency increase; you only ever have to look at each element in the initial array *once* (resulting in `n`, or linear, time complexity)!

If you want to combine the above object back into an array, you could then do:

```
// get object keys
var objectKeys = Object.keys(combinedDates);
var newArray = [];

// loop through keys
for (var makeObject = 0; makeObject < objectKeys.length; makeObject++) {
  // create array with key (the date) and the number (the value stored at the key):
  newArray.push([objectKeys[makeObject][0], combinedDates[objectKeys[makeObject]]);
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code