# Total JavaScript Array by one Property

Tags: javascript, reduce

I've looked at lots of examples but cannot get this to work.  At best, I end up with a version of the existing array with properties replicated that should be lost in the summary.

I would like to output a new array of totals for each location and not include any details for specific periods, the period property etc.
I think my issue is with Object.assign({}, o); where I am creating a full copy, but I can't see how to just create an object with just the location, to which the totals can be added.

This is a simplified example and in the original I am summing multiple columns and dropping multiple columns.

```js
let helper = {};
let locationPeriodCounts = [
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "228", "countIn": 6, "countOut": 1},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "228", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 2},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "228", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 3},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "228", "countIn": 1, "countOut": 4},
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "229", "countIn": 5, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "229", "countIn": 18, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "229", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "230", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-25", "location": "230", "countIn": 4, "countOut": 6}
];

let locationCounts = locationPeriodCounts.reduce(function(r, o) {
  let key = o.location;
  if (!helper[key]) {
    helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    helper[key].totalCountIn = 0;
    helper[key].totalCountOut = 0;
    r.push(helper[key]);
  } else {
    helper[key].totalCountIn += o.countIn;
    helper[key].totalCountOut += o.countOut;
  }
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(locationCounts);
```

This is what I'm looking for as output...

```
[
  {"location": "228", "totalCountIn": 18, "totalCountOut": 10},
  {"location": "229", "totalCountIn": 31, "totalCountOut": 18},
  {"location": "230", "totalCountIn": 7, "totalCountOut": 12}
];
```

Comment: Added required output @mplungjan

Comment: Updated the code to produce an objectArray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group by and sum an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364262/how-to-group-by-and-sum-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added an Object.entries to convert to object array

We now need to spread the nested object to have both counters on the same level as the location

```js
let locationCounts = Object.entries(
  locationPeriodCounts
  .reduce(function (acc, { location, countIn, countOut }) {
    acc[location] ??= { totalCountIn: 0, totalCountOut: 0 }; // create if it does not exist
    acc[location].totalCountIn += countIn; // always add to the total
    acc[location].totalCountOut += countOut; // always add to the total
    return acc;
  }, {})
)
.map(([location, { totalCountIn, totalCountOut }]) => ({ location, totalCountIn, totalCountOut }));

console.log(locationCounts);
```

```html
<script>
let locationPeriodCounts = [
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "228", "countIn": 6, "countOut": 1},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "228", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 2},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "228", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 3},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "228", "countIn": 1, "countOut": 4},
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "229", "countIn": 5, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "229", "countIn": 18, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "229", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "230", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-25", "location": "230", "countIn": 4, "countOut": 6}
];
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. How is totakCount specifically getting set? If I want to add two values into two totals, how would I do that (for the purpose here, we can just add countIn to two totals)?

Comment: My code creates an object: `{ "228":0,"229":0,"230":0}` and adds to each of them by location. Then it converts that object to an object array and replaces `228` with `"location":"228"` and replaces `18` with `"totalCount":18`.  Again please show expected output when you ask to transform some input

Comment: Apologies @mplungjan, I've clarified the code to demonstrate I need it to work with multiple properties.

Comment: See updated code. I am now spreading the nested counters to put them on the same level as the location

Answer (score 2):

Your use of a 'helper' object in your original code is not a bad inclination and a common group-by pattern using `reduce` does just that by holding a result array in the accumulator object passed to `reduce`. The benefits include not needing to serialize the object after reducing and the 'helper' object is discarded after the reduce call is completed and the result array retrieved.

```js
let locationCounts = locationPeriodCounts.reduce(
  (acc, { location, countIn, countOut }) => {
    if (acc[location] === undefined) {
      acc[location] = { location, totalCountIn: 0, totalCountOut: 0 };
      acc._.push(acc[location]); // push a reference to the result array
    }
    acc[location].totalCountIn += countIn;
    acc[location].totalCountOut += countOut;
    return acc;
  },
  { _: [] } // declare a result array in the accumulator
)._; // retrieve the result array

console.log(locationCounts);
```

```html
<script>
let locationPeriodCounts = [
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "228", "countIn": 6, "countOut": 1},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "228", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 2},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "228", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 3},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "228", "countIn": 1, "countOut": 4},
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "229", "countIn": 5, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "229", "countIn": 18, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "229", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "230", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-25", "location": "230", "countIn": 4, "countOut": 6}
];
</script>
```

##### Without destructuring

```js
let locationCounts = locationPeriodCounts.reduce(
  (acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj.location;

    if (acc[key] === undefined) {
      acc[key] = {
        location: obj.location,
        totalCountIn: 0,
        totalCountOut: 0,
      };
      acc._.push(acc[key]);
    }

    acc[key].totalCountIn += obj.countIn;
    acc[key].totalCountOut += obj.countOut;

    return acc;
  },
  { _: [] }
)._;

console.log(locationCounts);
```

```html
<script>
let locationPeriodCounts = [
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "228", "countIn": 6, "countOut": 1},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "228", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 2},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "228", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 3},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "228", "countIn": 1, "countOut": 4},
  {"period": "2023-10-21", "location": "229", "countIn": 5, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-22", "location": "229", "countIn": 18, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-23", "location": "229", "countIn": 8, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-24", "location": "230", "countIn": 3, "countOut": 6},
  {"period": "2023-10-25", "location": "230", "countIn": 4, "countOut": 6}
];
</script>
```

---

##### Your existing code

All you were missing was creating a new object with only the relevant properties (correctly noted as an issue with `Object.assign()` in your question). Either using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as above, or manually as you currently are.

To make your own code work as is, simply replace `helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o);` with `helper[key] = { location: o.location };`, and move the summation out of the `else` block. This still leaves `helper` hanging around in the global scope, but that is easily fixed by passing it as a closure:

```
let locationCounts = (helper =>
  locationPeriodCounts.reduce(function (r, o) {
    let key = o.location;
    if (!helper[key]) {
      helper[key] = { location: o.location };
      helper[key].totalCountIn = 0;
      helper[key].totalCountOut = 0;
      r.push(helper[key]);
    }

    helper[key].totalCountIn += o.countIn;
    helper[key].totalCountOut += o.countOut;

    return r;
  }, []))({});
```

or using the setup described above.

Answer (score 1):

I found [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)'s response much more smart and compact than mine.
This, however, is what I usually do:

```js
let locationPeriodCounts = [
    { "period": "2023-10-21", "location": "228", "countIn": 6 },
    { "period": "2023-10-22", "location": "228", "countIn": 8 },
    { "period": "2023-10-23", "location": "228", "countIn": 3 },
    { "period": "2023-10-24", "location": "228", "countIn": 1 },
    { "period": "2023-10-21", "location": "229", "countIn": 5 },
    { "period": "2023-10-22", "location": "229", "countIn": 18 },
    { "period": "2023-10-23", "location": "229", "countIn": 8 },
    { "period": "2023-10-24", "location": "230", "countIn": 3 },
    { "period": "2023-10-25", "location": "230", "countIn": 4 }
]

let locationCounts = locationPeriodCounts.reduce((acc, { location, countIn }) => {

    let currLocationCount = acc.find(count => count.location === location)

    if (currLocationCount) {
        currLocationCount.totalCount += countIn
    } else {
        acc.push({
            location: location,
            totalCount: countIn
        })
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

//If you also need sorting
locationCounts.sort((a, b) => {
    //return a.totalCount - b.totalCount // asc
    return b.totalCount - a.totalCount //desc
})

console.log(locationCounts);
```

And this is the output:

```
[
   {location: "229", totalCount: 31},
   {location: "228", totalCount: 18},
   {location: "230", totalCount: 7}
]
```

Comment: This is much slower because of `find`

Comment: yeah, that's why I said @mplungjan is way more smart than mine!

Comment: But, a question: by doing `acc[location]` is accessing the array like an hashmap in ~ O(1) or doing an implicit find? Thank you so much!

Comment: In the other answer `acc` is not an array, it's an object, so `acc[location]` is most-likely O(1)

Comment: Uh, nice, thank you. Definitely interesting!